# JAX-RS Invoke endpoint based on header value

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Is there a way to use the same path but separated based on the value of the header with out spring framework. I'm looking for an equivalent of the below code in JAX-RS

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request", headers={"range=include"}) 
public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> processWithView() {
    return processRequestSomeOther();
}


// request handling (no headers specified) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/request")
public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> processWithoutView() {
    return processRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly like that.  But something like:

```
@Path("/request")
public ResponseEntity<SomeObject> processViews(@HeaderParam("range") String range) {
    if( range == null )
        return processRequest();

    return processRequestSomeOther();
}
```

will do the same thing.  Obviously you can parse the headers directly too.